# Probability of two packages of flour(N(1000g, 40g)) containing enough flour for 1900g Cake. (distribution-probability)

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**Relevant information**

Flour packages contain expected value of 1000g flour with  normal distribution, and standard deviation of 40g.

***A)*** For a cake we need 950g of flour, what is the probability that we have enough flour in a package?

N(1000, 40)
Ok so this question is easy so far, but I need help with the second question.

***B)*** For two cakes we need **1900g** of flour. What is the probability that the **two packages** contain enough flour.

If I input N(2000,80) I get the same result as for A, which I assume is wrong. I'm not sure how to aproach this. Any help would be appreciatet, or just links to the theory.

Sorry for any grammar mistakes, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

For b), you need to *add* two normally distributed random variables. In that case, you simply add the standard deviations under quadrature (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)), such that the effective standard deviation becomes $\sqrt{2}\sigma=56.578\dots$

Answer (score 0):

The variance of the sum should be $40^2+40^2$ not $80^2$